# Upgrade from Lubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: upgrade

I have downloaded "Ubuntu 13.04_Raring Ringtail_Release i386", but it comes with two files: the first is iso, the second iso.part. I use Xfburn to make the iso file in the disk, and it can't recognize the second file "part.iso". Is somewhere available "Ubuntu 13.04_Raring Ringtail_Release i386" in an only file iso to download? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`.part` file means that's indicating that it is still in downloading or downloading process interrupted. I mean you have not completed the Downloading of your Ubuntu 13.04 ISO. Usually `.part` files will appear when ever we do downloading something.

Before going to burn the ISO I always recommended to check `md5sum` of that ISO to check for errors. [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)